# cakePHP Email Attachment

Tags: file, email, cakephp

I have this function in my controller that am using to send an email to the advertiser of a job in a site I am building; the function may look a bit overloaded but what it is basically doing is:

1. getting the details of the person applying for a particular job,
2. the details of the job, and
3. a resume

All this information  is bundled together and sent to the model after successful saving where the email is sent

```
    public function sendapplication() {

    if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
        $this -> JobApplication -> create();
        $userid = CakeSession::read("UserAuth.User.id");
        //this reads the current user id in the session established when the user logged in and uses it to store the job alert
        $this -> JobApplication -> data['JobApplication']['user_id'] = $userid;

        //$this -> JobApplication -> data['JobApplication']['job_post_id'] = $this -> JobApplication -> JobPost -> id;
        $job_post_id = CakeSession::read('jobpost.id');//reading the job id session set above
        $this -> JobApplication -> data['JobApplication']['job_post_id'] = $job_post_id;

        $minorjobdetails = $this -> JobApplication -> sendapplicationmodel($job_post_id);

        foreach ($minorjobdetails as $minorjobdetail) :
            $this -> JobApplication -> data['JobApplication']['jobTitle'] = $minorjobdetail['JobPost']['jobTitle'];
            $this -> JobApplication -> data['JobApplication']['employer'] = $minorjobdetail['JobPost']['contactName'];
        endforeach;

        $jobless = $this->JobApplication->JobPost->findById($job_post_id );
        $job_applicant = $this->JobApplication->User->findById($userid);

        $job_resume = $this -> request-> data['JobApplication']['resume_id'];
        $attachedresume = current($this -> request-> data['JobApplication']['quickresume']);
        $attachedresumepath = next($this -> request-> data['JobApplication']['quickresume']);
        $attachedresumepath1 = next($this -> request-> data['JobApplication']['quickresume']);
        $this -> log('Job resume id-' . $job_resume, LOG_DEBUG);
        if ($this -> JobApplication -> save($this -> request -> data, false)) {
            //$this->JobApplication->sendJobApplicationMail();
            //$this -> Session -> setFlash(__('job application sent'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('job application sent successfully', 'success', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            $this->JobApplication->sendJobApplicationMail($jobless, $job_applicant, $job_resume, $attachedresume, $attachedresumepath, $attachedresumepath1);
            $this->JobApplication->deliveryReportEmail($job_applicant, $jobless);
            $this -> redirect('/jobsposted');
        } else {
            $this -> Session -> setFlash(__('job application could not be sent. Please, try again.'));
        }

    }

}
```

There are two instances of resumes; a user might have uploaded to the server before or is attaching when he/she is applying for the job. My problem is comes when attachment is made on the form. this is my form:

```
    <?php 

        echo $this->Form->create('JobApplication', array('type' => 'file', 'enctype' =>'multipart/form-data', 'controller' => 'JobApplications', 'action' => 'sendapplication'));


        foreach($jobseeker as $js):
        echo $this->Form->input('fullname', array('class' => 'span6', 'value' => $js['User']['first_name']));
        // debug($js['User']['first_name']);

        echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('class' => 'span6', 'value' => $js['User']['last_name'] ));
        echo "<div class=\"input-prepend\">";
        echo $this->Form->label('email');
        echo "<span class=\"add-on\"><i class=\" icon-envelope\"></i></span>".$this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'span6', 'value' => $js['User']['email'], 'label' => false, 'div' => false));
        echo "</div>";
        endforeach;
        echo $this->Form->input('comment_application_letter', 
                                    array(
                                            'type' => 'textarea',
                                            'rows'=>10,
                                            'cols' => 50,
                                            'class' => 'span6', 
                                            'label' => 'Comment/ Application letter', 
                                            'placeholder' => 'E.g. My name is John Doe. I would like to apply for the marketing job position as posted on ABC company site on mm/dd/yyyy'
                                    )
                                );


        echo $this->Form->input('JobApplication.resume_id', array('label' => 'Select resume', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $myResume));
        // echo $this->Form->label($fieldName = 'selected-file', $text = 'Resume:');

        // echo $this->Form->input('JobApplication.dropboxurl',array('type'=>'dropbox-chooser', 'name'=>'selected-file', 'id'=>'db-chooser', 'label' => false, 'visibilty' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('JobApplication.quickresume', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => 'Attach resume'));
        // echo $this->Form->input('', array('label' => 'Resume url', 'id' => 'dropboxurl', 'type' => 'text', 'div' => false, 'disabled', 'value' => '', 'class' => 'span6'));

        echo "<br>";

        echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'),array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'))

    ?>
```

From the form I want to get the resume that has been attached and send it alongside the details of the user; 
Below is the function in the model that is responsible for sending the email

```
public function sendJobApplicationMail($jobless, $job_applicant, $job_resume, $attachedresume, $attachedresumepath, $attachedresumepath1) {
    // send email to newly created user
    $userId = $jobless['JobPost']['id'];
    $email = new CakeEmail();

    $fromConfig = 'example@example.com';
    $fromNameConfig = 'Jobs';
    $email -> from(array($fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
    $email -> sender(array($fromConfig => $fromNameConfig));
    $email -> to($jobless['JobPost']['jobapplicationEmail']);
    $email -> subject(SITE_NAME . ': ' . __('Job Application'));

    if(!empty($attachedresume)){
        //file 
        pr($attachedresume);
        pr($attachedresumepath);
        pr($attachedresumepath1);

    // pr($email->filePaths = array($attachedresumepath1)); 
    // exit;
    $email -> attachments(array('CV'=> $attachedresume));
//exit();
    }



    $email -> emailFormat('html');
    $email -> template('applicant', 'fancy');
    $email -> theme('Default');
    $email -> viewVars(array('employer' => $jobless['JobPost']['contactName'], 'applicant_fname' => $job_applicant['User']['first_name'], 'applicant_sname' => $job_applicant['User']['last_name'], 'aplicant_email' => $job_applicant['User']['email']));

    // $employer_contact_name = $jobless['JobPost']['contactName'];
    // $job_applicant_fname = $job_applicant['User']['first_name'];

    //$email->transport('Debug');
    $body = __('Hi %s,<br/><br/>The below named person has shown interest on a job you posted;the details of the applicant are as follows: %s.<br/><br/>Thanks,<br/>%s', $jobless['JobPost']['contactName'], $job_applicant['User']['first_name'], SITE_NAME);
    try {
        $result = $email -> send($body);
        $this -> log('Job apllication mail sent to job post id-' . $userId, LOG_DEBUG);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // we could not send the email, ignore it
        $result = "Could not send job application  email to userid-" . $userId;
        $this -> log($result, LOG_DEBUG);
    }
}
```

I have been trying to debug and this is what I get when I try to submit the form;

**File not found: ""**

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

**Stack Trace**
APP/Model/JobApplication.php line 98 → CakeEmail->attachments(array)
array( 'CV' => 'CAT 1 EvnCourseMay13.doc' )

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I do not have an issue with sending resumes uploaded on the server before, my issue is with resumes that are attached on the form at the moment when one is applying for the job. The getResume() function is basically getting a resume that one had previously uploaded. To make this easier, I am actually trying to achieve emailing details(that includes a file) from a form to aparticular person. The getResume() has totally nothing to do with this because for it the resumes are in the server

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is pretty clear: The file can not be found. Debug your code (Unit tests for the win) and figure out why the passed file path value is empty or the wrong file path.

I would say the issue is that you're missing to pass the whole path, you just use the file name. Read the stack trace.

And by the way: If you don't want to allow these files to be public accessible you should not put them into the webroot... And there is a bunch of other issues with the way you store the files but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that but where else can I store them?

Comment: Another thing, those files on the server i have no problem attaching them on the email. my problem is with the files attached on the above form